Cannot print links when scraping for news
id like to have a list of titles and links for the relevant news articles on the page. i can print just the titles but for some reason the links remain illusive.
here is the python code that I'm using. I was expecting to get a big blob of html, followed by list of titles and links. all i got was the blob and the titles not sure what the issue is and id love some insight on this topic if anyone knows what's going on
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/industries/energy/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('h3', class_ = "Mb(5px)") #all of the relevant articles loaded on the page  


print(articles)                                    # prints the html including the title and link 

for items in articles:  
    
    title = items.text                            #titles print no problem
    link = items.absolute_links                   #no links are being printed 
    print(title , link)



I don't know where you found this code, but this isn't working, because there is no "absolute_links" attribute for the elements you're getting. What you can do instead is getting the 'a' tag from the elements and get the links from their 'href', if they have one. For external sites you get absolute links here, for site-internal links only links relative to the 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/' base. Your best bet is to check each link whether or not it is an absolute one and if not simply add the base in front. For instance, you can check whether it starts with https:// or something like that. There are also some modules that may cover all your cases, but that's a matter of taste / dependency requirements of your project.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/industries/energy/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('h3', class_ = "Mb(5px)") 

for items in articles:
    try:
        title = items.text                            
        link = items.a['href']                    
        print(title , link)
        # add some logic to turn relative to absolute links
    except KeyError:
        # no href in a
        pass
    except TypeError:
        # no a in item
        pass 

